# onChange and setState don't work together in my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

I am trying to build a search box. However, when I want to set the state when something is typed in, the box just simply doesn't let me type in anything.

This is the class which calls the component of search box

```
export default class Tagsearch extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      hitsDisplay:false,
      inputContent:"",
      tags:[]
    };
  }
  openDisplay = () => {
    console.log("open")
    // this.setState({ hitsDisplay: true })
  }

  closeDisplay = () => {
    console.log("close")
    // this.setState({ hitsDisplay: false })
  }

  render() {

    let inputTags = (
      this.state.tags.map((tag, i) => 
        <li key={i} style={styles.items}>
          {tag}
          <button onClick={() => this.handleRemoveItem(i)}>
            (x)
          </button>
        </li>
      )
    )

    let result = (
      <div className="container-fluid" id="results">

      </div>
    )

    if (this.state.hitsDisplay) {
      result = (
        <div className="container-fluid" id="results">
          <div className="rows">
            <MyHits handleSelect={this.handleSelect}/>
          </div>

          <div className="rows">
            <Pagination />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return (
      <InstantSearch
        appId="*******"
        apiKey="***********************"
        indexName="tags"
      >
        {inputTags}
        <SearchBox  
          connectSearchBox={connectSearchBox}
          openDisplay={this.openDisplay}
          closeDisplay={this.closeDisplay}
        />
        {result}

      </InstantSearch>
    )
  }
}
```

The following is the search box component

```
const SearchBox = props => {

  let { 
    connectSearchBox,
    openDisplay,
    closeDisplay
  } = props;

  const CustomSearchBox = connectSearchBox(({ currentRefinement, refine }) => {
    const handleChange = (e, refine) => {
      refine(e.target.value)
      // console.log(e.target.value)
      if (e.target.value !== "") {
        openDisplay();
      } else {
        closeDisplay();
      }
    }

    return (
      <label>
        <ul style={styles.container}>
          <input
            style={styles.input}
            type="text"
            value={currentRefinement}
            onChange={e => handleChange(e, refine)}
          />
        </ul>
      </label>
    )
  })

  return (
    <CustomSearchBox />
  )
}

export default SearchBox;
```

If I comment the two setStates in open & closeDisplay, It work fine, it prints out open and close accordingly. However, once I enable setState, the input box simply doesn't allow me to type in anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: change `onChange` in your input to `onChange={this.handleChange(e,refine)}` and see if the problem persists

Comment: It doesn't work since the handleChange method is in the same const. It will give you an error like:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleChange' of undefined

Comment: The problem might be here: `value={currentRefinement}`. You are not changing the value of `currentRefinement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incorrectly written. `connectSearchBox` is meant to wire up a component to the Algolia api. It's a one time setup on a component definition. It returns a higher order component that wraps the given component with api features. You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/blob/master/packages/react-instantsearch-core/src/core/createConnector.js). By putting your custom SearchBox inside the SearchBox function, you are causing the component to be rebuilt and reconnected on each render() cycle, thereby not preserving state. This is why as soon as you `setState` your search text disappears.

```
import { connectSearchBox } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';

const CustomSearchBox = ({ currentRefinement, refine, openDisplay, closeDisplay, ...props }) => {
    const handleChange = (e, refine) => {
      refine(e.target.value)
      if (e.target.value !== "")
        openDisplay();
      else
        closeDisplay();
    }

    return (
      <label>
        <ul style={styles.container}>
          <input
            style={styles.input}
            type="text"
            value={currentRefinement}
            onChange={e => handleChange(e, refine)}
          />
        </ul>
      </label>
    )
  })

export default connectSearchBox(CustomSearchBox);
```

Usage

```
import CustomSearchBox from './CustomSearchBox'
...
       <CustomSearchBox  
          openDisplay={this.openDisplay}
          closeDisplay={this.closeDisplay}
        />
```

Usage example from the [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/search-box/react/?language=php#full-example). I think what you were trying to achieve was to pass props down to your component but the `connectSearchBox` already guarantees that any props you pass to the HOC also gets passed down to the your custom search box. [Line 335](https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/blob/06a63124c2af322b1b0dd556b41717ea799b41d6/packages/react-instantsearch-core/src/core/createConnector.js#L335)